# How to get the first point of intersection

Tags: c#, math, xna, collision

I am making a game similar to Terraria (with XNA 4.0 in C#) with tiles and entities. I have created functions that calculate (using axis aligned bounding boxes) if an NPC or such will collide with a tile at the current velocity.

In want a function that calculates the position of the axis aligned rectangle when it first hits a tile (the tiles are stored in an 2d array and each tile is 1 unit long and half a tile is 0.5 and so on), It is basically like traversing from where the rectangle currently is to where it will be until it hits a tile and returning the position. (I would prefer something more processing efficient for higher framerate).

I tried making it so that if the object will collide at it's current velocity then it doesn't move. But if the object it moving fast then it causes it to stop short of a possible collision. Anyway I want the information about where the rectangle first collided for making objects bounce around and so on (and for making things not be able to go through walls etc).

This question is pretty specific and if I need to clarify anything tell me.

Comment: It's worth noting that generally physics engines will allow objects to intersect after updating positions. Then they run a collision pass and separate colliding objects, rather than preventing the collision in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! I've modified the mechanicals of the game to cater for this idea. This page: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/math-and-physics/a-verlet-based-approach-for-2d-game-physics-r2714 - Helped quite a bit but I don't really need a full down tutorial on rigid body 2D physics.

Comment: Basically you have to scale your axis aligned rectangle with the vector time * velocity, until it collides with the tile. Additional Info: http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/04/20/collision-detection-for-dummies/